# Content type 'Product Display' not available when creating new View

Tags: commerce

I am working through the "Advanced Product Display Listing using Views" guide [here](https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce1/user-guide/products/setting-up-a-product-catalog#advanced).
When creating the new View, I do not have the option to select 'Product Display' as a content type.
Is there a configuration setting I have missed when installing Commerce from scratch?

Thanks,
Geoff.

Drupal 7.67,
Commerce 1

Comment: If you're starting a new site, I highly suggest you use D8 or D9 with Commerce 2 instead.

Comment: Thanks @NoSssweat, it is an old site, we are waiting on a few module updates before we can move to D8. Hopefully soon!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For D7, Commerce 1, unless you use [Commerce Kickstart](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart), you have to manually create it. Follow [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nqsyUeTiB_g&t=317s).

Comment: Thanks heaps No Sssweat, I thought that might be the case. I'll get to it.